# Is there a working solution to open pcap files in VS Code?

Tags: ssh, vscode-extensions, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I am currently connected via VS Code ssh to a remote machine running some program. I want to open and view the produced pcap files on this machine through VS Code on my local machine and by that prevent to always transfer them. I got the `vsc-webshark` extension for VS Code but it asks for the `Sharkd Full Path`. However, under my Windows installation of Wireshark at my local machine there is no sharkd binary and I cannot find how to download it. Moreover, on the remote machine I am not allowed to add any software since I am not root and can't become one.
Does anybody know a workaround or solution to this?
[Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mbehr1.vsc-webshark) it is suggested to download the portable packages and point the path to the extracted folder. However, this does not work for me either.
Thanks in advance

Downloaded the extension from VS Code marketplace and expected to be able to open the pcap files.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Windows. On my Mac I typed `which sharkd` to find the "sharkd" location after installing Wireshark. In my `settings.json` for VS Code, I use:

"vsc-webshark.sharkdFullPath": "`/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/sharkd`"

Comment: That's because the Wireshark macOS application bundle, as built by the Wireshark developers, includes sharkd; the Wireshark Windows installer, as built by the Wireshark developers, does *not* install sharkd.  See Wireshark issue #19556 at https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/19556.